# New-AzureDnsRecordSet not found anymore

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Recently switched to a new machine, and installing all Azure powershell modules etc. I can no longer find the cmdlet New-AzureDnsRecordSet. The DNS Zone I currently have is based on service management not ARM, so I can't use the new ARM cmdlets. I can see majority of the other Azure service management commands, but not these ones.

I've tried:

```
Install-Module Azure
Import-Module Azure
```

nothing is adding those cmdlets in. The new Rm cmdlets are there, and you can see some Azure modules are there. Do I need to recreate the DNSzone with the new Rm cmdlet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the **`New-AzureDnsRecordSet`** cmdlet has been deprecated in the latest version of Azure module as you have shown, which implies you can no longer create new Azure DNS record set in Classic (Service Management) mode.

You will need to create new Azure DNS Record Set with the new RM cmdlet (**`New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet`**) if you are using the latest Azure PowerShell version.

Hope that answers your question.